# jquery toggleClass not working on img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons ("Approve","Unapprove") and an image of a loading spinner.  By default the Approve button is showing and the Unapprove button and loading spinner image are hidden.

When the "Approve" button is clicked I want it to disappear, show the loading spinner, and then perform an ajax request.  On completion of the request, I want the loading spinner image to get hidden again.  If the ajax request was successful, I want the "Unapprove" button to show.  If the ajax request failed, I want the "Approve" button to show again.

The problem I have is that upon completion of the ajax request, my .always() method runs but the spinner image does not get hidden.  Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebme6fjs/7/

If I change the url of my ajax request to give me a 404 not found error, this process works like it's supposed to:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebme6fjs/8/

Does anyone know why in my first case the `spinner.toggleClass("hide");` command isn't running in the always() function?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
One interesting thing I found is that if I redefine my spinner variable in the .always() function, it works correctly on a succesful ajax request:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebme6fjs/9/

If you modify the ajax url to receive a 404 though, the same problem of the spinner not disappearing happens again.

Comment: In done, you are retoggling hide class on the image, you should use: `var otherButton = currentButton.siblings("button");`  https://jsfiddle.net/ebme6fjs/11/  And your UPDATE jsFiddle is wrong, in always callback, `this` doesn't refer to the clicked element but jqXHR option. So in fact, you aren't toggling class of image in always callback, **just** in done

Comment: Please post code here. If JSFiddle decides to pack up, your question is worthless to people coming after

Comment: @A.Wolff you found the correct issue by noting that I was calling siblings() instead of siblings("button").  If you want to answer I can mark yours as correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you were toggling `hide` class on image twice, in `always()` callback and `done()/fail()` ones.

This is because you were targeting image in both variables, `spinner` **&** `otherbutton`.

You should define `otherbutton` as following:

```
var otherButton = currentButton.siblings("button");
```

Not including image in matched set.

As a side note, for code readability, you should use `addClass()/removeClass()` instead as noted in KWeiss answer and btw, set all your logic for displaying/undisplaying elements only in `always()` callback.

Answer (score 2):

In a context where you **always** want to add the class, use `addClass`, not `toggleClass`. In your code, the class is toggled twice: Once in "always" and then again in "fail". So it ends up in the same state as before.

The reason you are targeting the image twice, is because you are defining otherButton like this:

```
var otherButton = currentButton.siblings();
```

When what you want to do is this:

```
var otherButton = currentButton.siblings('button');
```

`toggleClass` is most useful when you might want to add **or** remove the class depending on some condition.

Comment: The same element is not being toggled in all three of those locations.  Spinner is being toggled in always(), and currentButton and otherButton are toggled in fail() and done() respectively.

I can use addClass/removeClass if that is best practice however.  Doing so doesn't solve my issue though.